# A Single Computation Engine to Connect to Cloud and On-Prem Supporting ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, bigdata

I'm trying to find a big data solution as a computation engine (like SQL engine or Machine Learning) to support simultaneous connections to AWS, GCP and Azure storages and their managed SQL services as well as On-Prem clusters like Hadoop which supports data security, fine grained ACL, lineage graph and data governance.

Having known that cloud services don't support connections to other clouds, I know there is a Hadoop solution to address this problem using Hive and Ranger, but Hive has performance drawbacks especially compared to Spark and Presto.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you believe that cloud services don't support connections to other clouds? Your question is too broad and vague to be answered on SO. Please rewrite your questing asking one thing. You will have a better chance of an answer. It is OK to create many posts, one for each question. Remember this is a programming site. Ask programming questions.

Comment: "Why do you believe that cloud services don't support connections to other clouds?" show me some examples please

Comment: Show me where you cannot. This is your question.

Comment: So here is the question: Can an AWS managed service like Glue crawl a bucket in Google Storage or Athena query Google storage files?

Comment: Create a question as a POST. Go back and read my first comment. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask